# SpiderClusterManager exists in React-Azure-Maps?

Tags: reactjs, azure-maps

I need to show clustered items the same way they are showed on the vanilla js sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Symbol%20Layer/Expanding%20Spider%20Clusters/Expanding%20Spider%20Clusters.html

I tried checking the properties of most of the stuff on the library, but i can't find that feature , does anyone know if its available or there is a similar option when working with azure maps?

Answer (score 0):

The spider cluster module is a custom module that is not a built in part of Azure Maps. You can find this module here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-spider-clusters

You will need to host and load the `azure-maps-spider-clusters.min.js` file that's in the `dist` folder. If you are using TypeScript, there is a types file available that you can reference (I'm not exactly certain how to set that up within a react project).